# Html being added to Download file in response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm creating a csv file on the fly in my ASP.NET web app and sending it back to the user using the following code

```
ExportPlacementListPostModel postModel = CreatePostModelFromRequest();
MemoryStream stream = PlacementDatabaseController.ExportPlacementList(postModel);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=studentplacement.csv");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer());
```

Every time I download the file the web pages html is being appended onto the document.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here.

Colin G

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `Response.End()` after `Response.BinaryWrite` to prevent further output being written to the response.

Comment: The Response.End() answer from pmarflee is probably appropriate, but I believe you can also do: return;

Comment: any idea why this would happen on one server but not another?

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` can be used as well.

The `CompleteRequest` method causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the `EndRequest` event.

The `Response.End` method ends the page execution and shifts the execution to the `Application EndRequest` event in the application's event pipeline. The line of code that follows `Response.End` is not executed.

Here's a good read: [Don’t use Response.End() with OutputCache](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/773859.aspx)